# Issue with apostrophes in html and pound symbols

Tags: html, email, text, web, copy

I have a problem, some email and web designs i receive have ’ instead of ' in the text. This creates problems with rendering on some email clients and it's difficult to manually catch them all.

Is there any type of software or online script that converts these symbols (along with the £ sign) to HTML compatible text? Would notepad or anything work?

I

Comment: Curly quotes and the pound sign are perfectly "HTML compatible" as is. All you need to do is treat them correctly and *handle encodings correctly*. If still "some email clients" are having a problem with them, you need to provide more details about what exactly you're doing and what exactly that problem is.

Comment: Does this have something to do with the charset? my current files are set as utf-8. If an email i code has a curly quote or pound symbol in the body section and i test it using emailonacid. It seems to stop rendering the rest of the email for all clients and browsers

Comment: You will need to provide more information about what exactly is happening and what exactly you're doing for me to say anything. But yes, it *probably* has something to do with charsets.

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to convert your text to html characters before putting it into your email html. This is a common issue when you import from MS Word, as it uses characters like curly quotes, hellips and mdashes that need converting first.

There are a whole bunch of converters out there, here are 3:

- [Email on Acid](http://www.emailonacid.com/character_converter/)
- [Web2Generators](http://www.web2generators.com/html/entities)
- [Charset](http://www.charset.org/html-special-characters.php)

Here is an example of something written in MS Word:

```
“Hello?” he said to ‘it’. Wait – I’m not finished…
```

This converts to this:

```
&ldquo;Hello?&rdquo; he said to &lsquo;it&rsquo;. Wait &ndash; I&rsquo;m not finished&hellip;
```

You should use the converted version in your email, or you could be lazy and just replace all instances of curly quotes with straight ones in your code. The grammar is not technically accurate, but most people will not mind.